# R - Finding common entries in columns from two separate tables

Tags: r

I am very new to R and apologize in advance if this question is too remedial.  I have downloaded two tables from an online database and would like to identify common (and unique) entries from two columns. I would like to compare the "Genome" column from Table "HPMT" with the "Specie" column from table "TS_COG". My code is below:

Import tables and identify columns:

```
HMPT=read.table("HMPtable.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", fill=TRUE)
GL=HMPT$Genome
TS=read.table("TS_COG.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", fill =TRUE )
SPL=TS$Specie
```

Identify common entries between two columns:

```
Same=intersect(GL, SPL)
Same
```

I have gone through the list generated by >Same and it appears to be too short.  I manually went through the two columns and found common entries which are not included in >Same.  There must be something wrong with my formatting or importing of the tables. Thank you in advance.

PS

Comment: How clean is your data? I would recommend both (1) setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your `read.table()` calls to make sure everything is imported as-is, and (2) set `strip.white = T` to get rid of any extra white space (also as an argument in `read.table`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  The data is pretty clean, i think.  Can you clarify?  I ve also tried by importing a bear column instead of the entire column and still no luck.  I should mention that the list are long: one table has 400 rwos comparing to one with 10 000 rows.

Comment: @Peter Spanos Could you try it on a smaller subset and see if the problem persists?  Also, in that case, you could show a small reproducible example using `dput`.

Comment: @PeterSpanos Seconding @akrun's comment. Basically, at this point, it sounds like you're doing something that should work, but it's not working on your data. So the problem is with your data, but we can't see it. As a bare minimum, post `dput(head(GL))` and the same for `SPL`. Better yet, find a subset that doesn't work as expected and post that.

Comment: I fixed the problem.  The problem must have been with my data, correct.  Even when i shortened the list it was still not working.  I used this: >TS=read.csv("TS_COG.csv") instead of the read.table .  This seemed to work.  Not sure why, but im happy.  Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility for the mentioned problem in the post would be:

```
GL <- c("A1", "A2 ", " A3")
TS <- c(" A1", "A2 ", "A3", "A4", "A5 ")

intersect(GL,TS)
#[1] "A2 "
```

You can correct this by either using `str_trim` to remove the leading/lagging spaces.

```
library(stringr)
intersect(str_trim(GL), str_trim(TS))
#[1] "A1" "A2" "A3"
```

or use `gsub`

```
 GL1 <- gsub("^ +| +$", "", GL)
 TS1 <-  gsub("^ +| +$", "", TS)
 intersect(GL1, TS1)
 #[1] "A1" "A2" "A3"
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however this did not solve the problem.  See comment above.

Answer (score 0):

## Assign same names for the specific columns of both the data frame

`HMPT$name <- HMPT$Genome`
`TS$name <- TS$Specie`

## This will list all the common entries in both the columns

```
common <- merge(HMPT, TS, by="name")
```